# One-Hot encoded variables dominates importance among other variables

Tags: regression, linear-regression, decision-trees, feature-engineering, one-hot-encoding

I am currently training some machine learning models to predict the 28-day compressive strength of cement, a continuous real-valued variable. The available dataset comprises samples from three distinct types of cement. To account for this, I've introduced two one-hot encoded variables to indicate the specific type of cement associated with each sample.

Upon fitting a linear regression model and analyzing the coefficients, I noticed that the the one-hot encoded variables presented the highest magnitude among all variables. Additionally, when employing a basic shallow decision tree, the resulting tree structure revealed that the one-hot encoded variables were the most informative. Surprisingly, when I removed these variables, the results given by evaluation metrics worsen. The results also worsen when training models individually for each type of cement in separate datasets.. Similar worsening in results occurred when training models individually on separate datasets for each cement type.

Here are statistical summaries for the target variable per cement type:

```
Cement type 1: Mean - 36.672927, Standard Deviation - 1.097930, Number of Samples - 611
Cement type 2: Mean - 47.470623, Standard Deviation - 1.181711, Number of Samples - 421
Cement type 3: Mean - 45.534391, Standard Deviation - 1.604127, Number of Samples - 234
```

From a domain knowledge perspective, regulatory standards dictate that cement type 1 should have a minimum value of at least 32, type 2 a minimum of 40, and type 3 a minimum of 34.

Is it possible that the prominence of these one-hot encoded variables over others stems from the low variability in the target variable per cement type? Additionally, could this be influenced by the possibility that the other variables may exhibit non-linear relationships with the target variable that cannot be captured by the linear model?

Might these factors constrain the model's predictions even more restricted to the range of values of the training set, potentially leading to misleading results?

Comment: To respond shortly, gender would be a one-hot-encoded variable in a model predicting probability of developing breast cancer, and it would be one of the most powerful variables there in the model - the cement types might just be that important of a variable in predicting the compressive strength given that the strength of cement depends on the type of cement. What other variables do you have? I worry there might be some strong correlation which is not good for regression models, stemming from the fact that type of cement dictates other properties you use as predictors

Comment: There are a total of 40 variables, in addition to those one-hot encoded. These variables include chemical, mineralogical, and physical characteristics of cement. The physical features encompass early curing ages of cement compressive strength at 3 and 7 days, which, in turn, represent the target variable at an early stage. Additionally, I conducted experiments using only chemical and mineralogical features, as well as experiments using all variables.

Comment: You should do some factor analysis or principal component analysis to reduce the correlation (combine the correlated features into one to reduce dimensionality) - linear regression is very fragile in terms of correlation. What is happening is that, in an easy example, you are trying to predict the age expectancy of an animal, but you only have cats and dogs with their 40 other properties to predict it, although the fact that the animal is a dog or a cat already affects the other 38 variables by itself. Same with "Type of cement" defined by it's properties being correlated to those properties.